# Flaw in A.M.-G.M. inequality for finding the range of function.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $f(x) =2^x+2^ {-x} +3^x+3^ {-x} +4$. The minimum value of this function is 8.
 Which comes as

$\dfrac{2^x+\frac{1}{2^x}}{2}\ge \sqrt{2^x\cdot\frac{1}{2^x}}$

$2^x+2^{-x}\ge 2$

similarly,

$3^x+3^{-x}\ge 2$

Both these terms have minimum value at x=0

But what if we us the inequality as-

$\dfrac{2^x+2^{-x}+3^x+3^{-x}+4}{5}\ge\sqrt[5]4$

Hence the minimum value comes out to be $\sqrt[5]4$ which is less than 8.

I cannot see any flaw in both of the methods. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee there ever has to be situation where the LHS value has to match the RHS value when using the AM-GM inequality. The inequality only states the $2$ *may* be equal, but the LHS is always at least the size of the RHS.

In your last equation, note that since $2^x + 2^{-x} \ge 2$ and $3^x + 3^{-x} \ge 2$, then $\frac{2^x + 2^{-x} + 3^x + 3^{-x} + 4}{5} \ge \frac{2 + 2 + 4}{5} = \frac{8}{5} \gt \sqrt[5]{4}$.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing that out, but why then why does it work with only exponential terms?

Comment: @user8791684 Note that equality is obtained when every term is equal - the fact that they're all exponential isn't important - but the fact that the terms are *equal* at $x=0$ is important. (Note that if you apply the inequality to $2^x+2^{-x}+3^x+3^{-x}+1+1+1+1$, it works out fine)

Comment: @user8791684 You're welcome. Note it doesn't *only* work with exponential terms. Milo Brandt's comment expands on this.

Comment: What about $2^x+3^{-x}$? Can we find its minimum value by this? (which is 1.949)

Comment: @user8791684 Good point. Thanks for mentioning it. This shows the LHS values being equal doesn't mean they equal the RHS value. Thus, I've updated my answer to remove the extra part about Milo's comment because it's not always true.

Comment: @JohnOmielan so is getting the correct minimum value a coincidence?

Comment: @MiloBrandt in the above case I mentioned, they inequality doesn't become equality even When they are equal....

Comment: @user8791684 Getting the "correct" (I assume you mean the min. indicated by the RHS) minimum value is not a "coincidence" (none of math really is), but it doesn't always happen and, I believe, it tends to not happen in many cases.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I mean the minimum value of such functions. And by correct I mean getting the actual minimum value of the function by the A.M.-G.M. inequality (or equality). If it doesn't always happen, and also not coincidence, how do we know it is the actual minimum or not?

Comment: @user8791684 There is no general method that I know of which always applies. Instead, determining whether or not the RHS is the actual minimum or not is done on a case by case basis, depending on the behavior of the functions involved.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I doubt getting correct Minimum value in $a^x+a^{-x}$ has anything to do with both terms being equal at 0

Comment: @user8791684 I am referring merely to the fact that the AM equals the GM at $0$ being equivalent to saying that every term is equal - which is absolutely true. The generalization I'm hinting at precisely is that if you have a sum $f_1(x)+f_2(x)+\ldots +f_n(x)$ where the product $f_1(x)\cdot f_2(x) \cdot \ldots \cdot f_n(x)$ is equal to some constant $C$ for all $x$, you can say that $f_1(x)+\ldots+f_n(x) \geq n\sqrt[n]{C}$ - but if there is some $x_0$ where all terms are equal, then the sum *equals* this lower bound, so is minimized at that $x_0$ (and this is the only way to obtain the min)