# Prove that ,$\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^{2}+\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^{2} \geq 8$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

For any positive a, b prove that $$\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^{2}+\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^{2} \geq 8$$

---

**My approach**:
*Using the well known inequality,*

$ \boxed{\mathrm{AM} \geq \mathrm{GM}}$

$\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^{2}+\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^{2} \geq 2 \sqrt{\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^{2}*\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^{2}}$

$\geq 2\left(a b+\frac{1}{a b}+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)$

*what to do next*??
**Any hint or suggestion would be greatly appreciated**

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3358146/flaw-in-a-m-g-m-inequality-for-finding-the-range-of-function ?

Comment: For $x>0$ we have $(x-1)^2 \geq 0 \implies x^2 + 1 \geq 2x \implies x + \frac{1}{x} \geq 2$. Similarly for $x<0$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$x+\frac  1 x \geq 2$ for any positive number $x$ by AM-GM inequality. Hence $(a+\frac  1a)^{2}+(b+\frac  1 b)^{2} \geq 2^{2}+2^{2}=8$.

Comment: great ,perfectly understood

Comment: My congratulations.

Answer (score 3):

To continue your approach, just apply AM-GM a second time

$$\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^{2}+\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^{2} \geq 2 \sqrt{\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^{2}\cdot\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^{2}}$$
$$=2\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right) \stackrel{AM-GM}{\geq}2\cdot 2\sqrt{a\frac 1a}\cdot 2\sqrt{b\frac 1b}=8$$

Minimum is achieved for $a=b=1$.