# Why does AM>GM when applied on functions gives the absolute minima.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

- In some cases we use the relation AM>GM to find the minima for example take $f(x)=x+\frac1x$ $[x\gt 0]$ using the result AM>GM we can find the minima as $2$.It is the same minima which we get if we use the methods of derivative.
- But why do we get the same minima why not say we get $f(x)>1$.This statement ($f(x)>1$) is not false but $1$ is just not the absolute minima.Can we prove that the relation AM>GM will always give the **absolute minima** *in the given domain*? (Note-I am **not** asking for the proof of result AM>GM.)
- Hence as we are getting the absolute minima using the result AM>GM I conclude that there is some kind of relation between applying the result $AM>GM$ and using the methods of derivative.Is there any intuitive way to understand that relation?

Comment: $$x+\frac{1}{x}=\frac x2+\frac x2+\frac1x$$ now apply the inequality.(without simplifying the result)

Comment: These [tv](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727632/find-the-minimum-of-x3-frac1x2-for-x0) [vo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3358146/flaw-in-a-m-g-m-inequality-for-finding-the-range-of-function) posts maybe helpful.

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- I feel that vo's answer was wrong because he/she unnecessary added one to the equation as you had commented... btw what does vo an tv stands for?

Comment: $$\text{tv vo }\rightarrow\text{ tvvo }\to \text{ two}$$xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AM-GM not always gives an extreme value. We need also to save the case of the equality occurring. In AM-GM it happens for equality case of all variables, which not always good.

Also, under AM-GM we have convexity of $\ln$, which has a relation with a second derivative.

Also, there are very many methods to find an extreme value with derivatives and these methods have no any relation with AM-GM.

For example.

Let we need to find a maximal value of $(a^2-ab+b^2)(a^2-ac+c^2)(b^2-bc+c^2)$ by AM-GM, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are non-negatives such that $a+b+c=3$.

We see that $(a,b,c)=(2,1,0)$ gives a value $12$.

We'll prove that $12$ is a maximal value.

We can not use AM-GM here in the following form. $$\prod_{cyc}(a^2-ab+b^2)\leq\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-ab+b^2)}{3}\right)^3$$ because it does not save the case of equality occurring.

For $(a,b,c)=(2,1,0)$ we obtain:
$$a^2-ab+b^2=3,$$$$a^2-ac+c^2=4$$ and $$b^2-bc+c^2=1,$$ which is not good because we need $$a^2-ab+b^2=a^2-ac+b^2=b^2-bc+c^2,$$ which is wrong and it says that we got a wrong inequality:
$$\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2-ab+b^2)}{3}\right)^3\leq12,$$ which easy to understand after checking $(a,b,c)=(2,1,0).$

By the way, the following solution saves the case of equality occurring.

Let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, $$(a^2-ab+b^2)(a^2-ac+c^2)(b^2-bc-c^2)\leq(a^2-ab+b^2)a^2b^2=$$
$$=((a+b)^2-3ab)a^2b^2\leq(9-3ab)a^2b^2=12(3-ab)\left(\frac{ab}{2}\right)^2\leq$$
$$\leq12\left(\frac{3-ab+\frac{ab}{2}+\frac{ab}{2}}{3}\right)^3=12.$$
Id est, we solved this problem by AM-GM.

Actually, using AM-GM was possible because for $(a,b,c)=(2,1,0)$ we have $$3-ab=\frac{ab}{2}=\frac{ab}{2}.$$
We can use the Lagrange Multipliers method here (id est, we can use derivatives),

but it not so easy here.

Comment: "In AM-GM it happens for equality case of all variables, which not always good." i am unable to understand this statement........thanks a bunch

Comment: @Thulashitharan I added an example. See now.

Comment: got it ...... :)....